# Linux command for store service log in multiple files

Tags: linux

Is there any command in Linux for capture logs in multiple files? This means if the size of a log is exceeding a specific size then create a new file.

i.e
java -jar myjar.jar >> templog.txt

The above command stores log in the templog.txt file but it does not create a new file (i.e templog.txt) after a certain log size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use logrotate this exactly for this. 
You can rotate log files based on schedule or size and the old files get new name.

See here: https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate 
And here more detailed post: https://www.tecmint.com/install-logrotate-to-manage-log-rotation-in-linux/

Answer (score 1):

add a entry to `logrotate`
(`etc/logrotate.d`)

```
/var/log/linuxserver/linux.log {
        rotate 7
        daily
        compress
        delaycompress
        missingok
        notifempty
        create 660 linuxuser linuxuser }
```